# Scatter a 2D numpy array in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 4x4 data array like

```
data = np.array([[0,1,1,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,0], [0,0,0,1]])
```

Now I want to scatter this array on a 2D plot.

If `data[i,j]` is equal to 1, there should be a colored spot at point (x,y)=(i,j). I've tried with scatter plot in matplotlib, but somehow couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[0,1,1,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,0], [0,0,0,1]])

# get the indices where data is 1
x,y = np.argwhere(data == 1).T

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, when you just want to visualize the 4x4 array you can use `matshow`

```
plt.matshow(data)
plt.show()
```